# Anyone knows how to add chromedriver.exe to path

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

i am getting an error called selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home,
i tried to automate google chrome but it says it needs to be in path can someone say how to add to path

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Java?
In Java you can use this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Replace path with your ChromeDriver Path